# How to set custom font for ListView row text?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a list with two elements I retrieve from db.
I am also using fragments … 
I want to style the text of each the rows in the list view in a custom way. 
The xml file where I have the textview that I use for the listView elements is:
useful_numbers_fragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/useful_nums_h_layout_header">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/useful_nums_group_item"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
   </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to set the typeface of this textview just like this :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View
 parent = inflater.inflate(R.layout.useful_numbers_fragment, container, false);
        Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/ArialNarrow.ttf");
        TextView tv = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.useful_nums_group_item);
        tv.setTypeface(t);
        return parent;
    }
```

but I get a 
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #98: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't be used with a custom content view
            at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.setEmptyText(ListFragment.java:234)
at …onViewCreated()...**

I resolved the problem in this way:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.useful_numbers_fragment, container, false);
        parent.addView(v, 0);
        Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/ArialNarrow.ttf");
        TextView tv = (TextView) parent.findViewById(R.id.useful_nums_group_item);
        tv.setTypeface(t);
        return parent;
    }
```

But the text font hasn’t changed.

```
SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder binder = new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/ArialNarrow.ttf");
                TextView tv=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.useful_nums_group_item);
                tv.setText(tv.getText());
                tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                tv.setTypeface(t);

                return true;
           }
        };
        simpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder(binder);
```

Comment: create `custom adapter` for listview and set external font inside `getView()`.

Comment: I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter ... I have edited my question with the code...The problem is that the text for my rows isn't appearing ...

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom adapter class which extends `SimpleCursorAdapter` in your `CustomAdapter` set external typeface.

Make some changes in `Fragment's onCreateView(...)`

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View v= (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.useful_numbers_fragment, null);
        Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/ArialNarrow.ttf");
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.useful_nums_group_item);
        tv.setTypeface(t);
        return v;
    }
```

Code snippet

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

            private Context mContext;
            private Context appContext;
            private int layout;
            private Cursor cr;
            private final LayoutInflater inflater;
            private Typeface t;

            public CustomAdapter(Context context,int layout, Cursor c,String[] from,int[] to) {
                super(context,layout,c,from,to);
                this.layout=layout;
                this.mContext = context;
                this.inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
                this.cr=c;
                t = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/ArialNarrow.ttf");
            }

            @Override
            public View newView (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                    return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
            }

            @Override
            public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
                TextView titleS=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TitleSong);
                TextView artistS=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Artist);
                titleS.setTypeface(t);
                artistS.setTypeface(t);
                int Title_index=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                int Artist_index=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

                titleS.setText(cursor.getString(Title_index));
                artistS.setText(cursor.getString(Artist_index));

            }

    }
```